# Break on space (Textbox)

Tags: c#, asp.net

In C# I know this

```
 if (textBox1.Text.Length > x)
    {
        textBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
    }
```

(x is some random number)
But what if I want to break on first space before x?

Comment: This is the perfect type of question to provide a couple of simple input-output examples. That will substantially improve the quality of answer you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your question is:

> I want to insert a new line at a space closest to "x" where the space's index does not exceed "x".

So given this example:

> The quick brown box jumped over the lazy dog.

And "X" is 30, then I would expect a new line to be inserted between "jumped" and "over".

I think this is something that would work for you:

```
var str = "The quick brown box jumped over the lazy dog.";
var x = 30;
var index = str.Select((c, i) => new {c, i}).TakeWhile(q => q.i < x).Where(q => q.c == ' ' ).Select(q => q.i).Last();
var formatted = str.Insert(index, Environment.NewLine);
```

Where `formatted` contains the new string with the line-break. Note that `Last()` will give an exception if there are no spaces in the string at all. In that case, use `LastOrDefault` and handle appropriately.

So given your example:

```
var x = 30;
if (textBox1.Text.Length > x) 
{
    var index = textBox1.Text.Select((c, i) => new {c, i}).TakeWhile(q => q.i < x).Where(q => q.c == ' ' ).Select(q => q.i).Last(); 
    textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Insert(index, Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This works perfect. Do you maybe have idea how to exclude some parameters from counting, like "@p", "@A" and similar, because they are used for text formatting.

Comment: @elninho [`Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.where.aspx) would be a good place to start, though your requirement isn't entirely clear to me. Can you give an example?

Comment: Text is like "Some text and @ASome red text" and that text is been sent to external application, which have custom text formatting, so for example, when I type @A all text after that @A becomes red, so I need to exclude those color triggers from counting.

Comment: @elninho Is it always an @ followed by a single character?

Comment: No. I have 8 "triggers" for colors (@ followed with single character) and 8 for color background (@ followed with 3 characters).

Answer (score 0):

Or simply use [LastIndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1tw91fa3.aspx) overload:

```
var current = textBox.Text;
textBox.Text = current.Insert(current.LastIndexOf(' ', 24), Environment.NewLine);
```

LastIndexOf will start searching at position `24`, moving **backwards** until it approaches first `' '`.

Comment: Poorly worded question, but I think he means *last* space before 'x'.

Answer (score -1):

insert a `Environment.NewLine` at the position of the first occurrence of `' '`
**UPDATE** added `SubString(0,X)` to meet the requirement "first space before position `X`"

```
textBox1.Text.Insert(textBox1.Text.SubString(0,X).IndexOf(' '), Environment.NewLine);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need first space **before** like 24th character. How can I include both statements?

Comment: Yes, by "first before x" I meant like "nearest before x"... So yes, you can say last before x, sorry.

Answer (score -1):

See if this helps:

```
            string text = "this is a long sentence";
            int x = 10;
            string updatedtext = string.Empty;
            updatedtext = text.Insert((x - 1) - text.Substring(0,x).Reverse().ToString().IndexOf(' '),Environment.NewLine);
```

Replace your textbox stuff with the appropriate variable.

Comment: LastIndexOf is a cleaner way of doing it like @Steve mentioned:

`string text = "this is a long sentence";
            int x = 10;
            string updatedtext = string.Empty;
            updatedtext = text.Insert(text.LastIndexOf(' ', x-1, x),Environment.NewLine);`

Answer (score -1):

If x is 20, and the textbox contains the string:

```
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
```

Then the code below will return:

```
    Lorem ipsum dolor 
    sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit

if (textBox1.Text.Length > x)
{
    int lastSpaceIndex = textBox1.Text.LastIndexOf(' ', x-1, x);
    if (lastSpaceIndex < 0)
        lastSpaceIndex = x;

    textBox1.Text.Insert(lastSpaceIndex, Environment.NewLine);
}
```

**EDIT** Corrected as per Mithun's comment below.

Comment: It should be 
`LastIndexOf(' ', x-1, x)`
LastIndexOf counts backwards.